# Is there a way to get the underlying NSURLErrorDomain (code) in React Native on iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, axios, fetch-api, nsurlsession

In our React Native app we use TrustKit for certificate pinning on iOS. If the certificate validation fails and I catch the error within the JavaScript context (example below), logging the error only shows a generic error message: `TypeError: Network request failed`.

Since the error doesn't stem from an http status code, like `404`, I believe I need to inspect the `NSURLErrorDomain` code ([for example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrorclientcertificaterejected?language=occ)) so that I can map it with the correct error handling. Are there any APIs in React Native, `fetch`, `axios`, or another package that would provide access to these error details?

```
fetch(myURL).then(() => true, (error) => {
    console.log(error) //TypeError: Network request failed
    return false;
})
```